# Checking if a User Has a Specific Role in Node.js with Elasticsearch ClusterClient

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, kibana, kibana-plugin

### Checking if a User Has a Specific Role

I'm trying to check if a user has a specific role using the following Node.js function. However, the `clusterClient.asInternalUser.security.getUser()` function returns information about all users in Kibana. My goal is to obtain the roles of the logged-in user.

```
const checkUserRole = (router, clusterClient) => {
  router.post(
    {
      path: '/api/check-user-role',
      validate: false,
    },
    async (context, request, response) => {
      try {
        // Using getUser function to retrieve user information
        const user = await clusterClient.asInternalUser.security.getUser();

        // Check if the user has a specific role
        if (user && user.roles && user.roles.includes('X')) {
          return response.ok({ body: { hasRole: true } });
        } else {
          return response.ok({ body: { hasRole: false } });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return response.badRequest({ body: { message: error.message } });
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Is this function correctly checking if the user has a specific role? What would be the best approach to retrieve logged-in user information? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's not the API you want.

[security.getUser()](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_get_user) is calling the [Get User API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-get-user.html) in Elasticsearch which lists all the users defined in the native & reserved realms. It does not return information

What you want to do is call the [authenticate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-authenticate.html) as the logged in user.

I believe you can do that with

```
clusterClient.asCurrentUser.security.authenticate();
```

(although there are other ways too).

*However*, are you sure you want to check for a specific role? That's not how Elastic's RBAC system is intended to work. The name of the role isn't supposed to be important, just the privileges it grants.

You are probably better off using the [Has Privileges API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-has-privileges.html) to determine whether the user is allowed to take some aciton, rather than whether they have a specific named role.

The [Security section in the Kibana Development Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/development-security.html) covers some of this.

Comment: Thank you I have just used hasPrivileges api, but this api returns sama response for different users who have different privileges

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you calling is with `asCurrentUser` or `asInternalUser`? If you're using the internal user, then it's making the call with the same user each time, so that won't achieve anything.